# Do you have to manually restart Gatsbyjs every time you post?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby.js. It seems like every time I write a new markdown post I have to stop and restart Gastsby with CTL+C and then npm run develop. Is that the normal procedure? It makes it hard to add content if I'm stuck doing that every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding posts the dev server automatically updates (no need to restart your dev server) I'm guessing it's a custom implementation issue. try following the official tutorial https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-four/ and see how it works for you.

note: the only reason to restart the server relates to changes (e.g. adding a new plugin) you do in your `gatsby-config.js`

Comment: Yeah, as part of writing the fourth part of the tutorial, I fixed this problem. Upgrade to the latest Gatsby and you should be good!